# How do I quit a mac application programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I need to add a quit-button to my application that runs from the menubar in mac.
How do I programmatically quit an application in mac?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There is a simpler form to quit from code:

```
[NSApp terminate:self];
```

But as you're adding a button, all you have to do is to control drag from your button to the Application icon and connect the method `terminate:`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll be adding my button in code, but thanks for the alternative solution as well.

Comment: Just curious, what IDE is this answer referring to?

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Xcode you should create a outlet between the button and the File's Owner placeholder, instead of the application.

Answer (score 23):

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:self];
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and `[NSApp terminate:self];`?

Comment: There is no difference, `NSApp` is the same as `[NSApplication sharedApplication]`.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
[NSApp terminate: nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

In some case you cannot close app when call `[NSApp terminate:self];`. Like when showing NSAlert as sheet on the doc window (`NSAlert -beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`) ...

You can close all window and alert before call terminate, like following code:

```
for (NSWindow *window in [NSApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
    [window close];
}
[NSApp terminate:self];
```

Comment: What else as `NSWindow` instances could the `windows` property of `NSApplication` return?

Comment: @vadian Oh yes, you are right windows is only return NSWindow. I will edit code

Answer (score 2):

Written in Swift:

```
NSApp.terminate(self)
```

or

```
NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
```